# PeerJS share one computer local stream to another computer in same network

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I am a newbie to WebRTC and PeerJS. My aim is to share Computer A local media stream to Computer B. I have successfully do this with the use of the cloud PeerJS server. However, I want to setup my server in local network.

Computer A is responsible for capturing the local media stream and I have the following code written.

```
var peer = new Peer('mycustomid1', {host: 'localhost', port: 9000});
```

Computer B is responsible for displaying the stream received from Computer A.

```
var peer = new Peer('mycustomid2', {host: 'Computer A's ipv4 address', port: 9000});
```

And I start my server with the code:

```
node peerjs --port 9000
```

Is my code correct? P.S. I can access Computer A localhost in a web browser on Computer B.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled a bit with setting up a peerserver. Try adding the key peerjs when you start the server. From the [github](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) page:

```
peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs
```

I think the key gets defaulted to 'peerjs' when you don't supply it when making a peer. Not to sure about this.

Also, try adding the default path when creating the peers.

```
var peer = new Peer('mycustomid2', {host: 'Computer A's ipv4 address', port: 9000, path: '/'});
```

Do this on both peers. Hope it helps